# Converting multipolygon data to polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, excel

I have a data set in Excel with several rows represents different polygon information. Polygon coordinates are provided in one columns as "Multipolygon". Example of one "Multipolygon" is given below;

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((145.7628 -36.5212, 145.7628 -36.5212, 145.7628 -36.5212, 145.7628 -36.5212)))
```

I want to import these data as polygon data set in ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Whoever gave you this, send it back. This is WKT of polygon and can be converted to polygon using arcpy.FromWKT(text). However all 4 points in your polygon are coincident, it makes NULL shape

Comment: It's also a *degenerate* multipolygon, because there is only one part. ArcGIS doesn't distinguish between polygons and multipolygons in most contexts, so that doesn't make much of a difference to it, but it does raise competency issues on the part of those generating the WKT string.

Comment: @Vince this #MULTIPOLYGON (((# is the start of any polygon WKT, count of parts doesn't matter

Comment: Not quite.  #POLYGON ((# is the proper form for single-part polygons.  If you export a geometry fashioned from a degenerate MULTIPOLYGON as WKT, it should show POLYGON on output.  The same applies to MULTILINESTRING and MULTIPOINT.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @FelixIP:

> This is WKT of polygon and can be converted to polygon using
>   arcpy.FromWKT(text). However all 4 points in your polygon are
>   coincident, it makes NULL shape.

and @vince:

> It's also a degenerate multipolygon, because there is only one part.
>   ArcGIS doesn't distinguish between polygons and multipolygons in most
>   contexts, so that doesn't make much of a difference to it, but it does
>   raise competency issues on the part of those generating the WKT
>   string.